# Hough Circle in c# , dynamic memory

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I have problem in dynamic memory allocation getting data from matrix

```
Image image_gray = new Image("im1.jpg");
Matrix circles = new Matrix(100, 1, 3);
```

Question 1: How can I locate dynamic memory because I don't know the number of circles?

```
Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvHoughCircles(image_gray, circles, HOUGH_TYPE.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
    2, 100, 200, 100, 10, 500);
```

Question 2: Now circle is matrix with [100 ,3], How can I get

```
point center= Round (circle[i][1], circle[i][1])
```

How can I get

```
int radius= circle[i][2];
```

what should my for loop look like to get data from matrix and casting should be point and int.

I tried already (NOT WORKING / ERROR)

```
for (int i=0; i < circles.Rows; i++) 
{ Matrix entry = circles.GetRow(i);

 float x = entry[0]; 
 float y = entry[1]; 
float r = entry[2];} // NOT WORKING
```

because instead of copying (required) only (i) row it copies whole matrix( circles) and float x=......gives errors

```
No overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments
```

please help me in this regard

regards

---

sorry to answer my question. please give some hint to dynamic memory allocation and matrix data

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific about what errors you are getting and where.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that it will grow the matrix to fit, but it also contradicts that, so honestly, I would try a 1 row 1 col matrix on an image with more circles and see what it gives you.  I see that you're using Matrix type - I don't know how you convert to the IntPtr needed by cvHoughCircles, but it should be straight forward to iterate over each row and pull out the results, which are 3 floats: (x, y, r) -

```
for (int i=0; i < circles.Cols; i++) {
    Matrix<float> entry = circles.GetRow(i);
    float x = entry[0]; // guessing here - the doc'n is truly awful
    float y = entry[1];
    float r = entry[2];
}
```